# The union of two sets A, B is the set AUB. Prove that if A and B are nonempty bounded subsets of R, then AUB is bounded and supAUB = max{supA, supB}.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Proof:

If A,B C R and are nonempty and bounded,

==> There exists a least upper bound M s.t: x <= M for all x in A or x in B, by the Completeness Axiom.

If A *and* B are bounded ==> AUB is bounded. Since AUB is bounded,

==> There exists a least upper bound M s.t: x <= M for x in AUB, by the Completeness Axiom.

So AUB has a supremum, namely the maximum of either set: supA or supB.

==> supAUB = max{supA, supB}. QED.

Thoughts?

Comment: Please learn how to use latex so that you can write your posts with the correct mathematical symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't prove the actual equation $\sup(A\cup B) = \max\{\sup A, \sup B\}$. To prove it, first note that for each $x\in A\cup B$, either $x\in A$ (which implies $x\le \sup A$) or $x\in B$ (which implies $x\le \sup B$); hence, for each $x\in A\cup B$, $x\le \max\{\sup A, \sup B\}$. Therefore, $\sup(A\cup B) \le \max\{\sup A, \sup B\}$. On the other hand, since $A \subseteq A\cup B$ and $B\subseteq A\cup B$, $\sup A \le \sup(A\cup B)$ and $\sup B \le \sup(A\cup B)$. Therefore, we get the reverse inequality $\max\{\sup A, \sup B\} \le \sup(A\cup B)$, which proves $\sup(A\cup B) = \max\{\sup A, \sup B\}$.